# Why is it possible to declare an array in C without defining its length?

Tags: c, arrays, initialization

In C you should define the length of an array. However, the following piece of code is valid:

```
int arr[] = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50};
```

Why is this acceptable syntax?

Comment: No one says, that you should do that, but one important thing will be if you pass it as argument of a function and you do not specify its length.

Comment: Short answer:  the initializer also defines the length of the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is acceptable, because the size (in bytes) of an integer is known during the compile time and thus the compiler knows how much space is required for that entire list.

But to understand this answer one has to dig a little deeper and ask why it is so important to know the exact size during the compile time. Generically speaking: To define the [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) for your program.
Part of that is the stack on which local variables are stored and which must not be confused with heap memory (where malloc works). The stack is a LIFO list and also contains all function calls together with its parameters. It is used in the end of a function to jump back, where you came from and has for that a memory address stored. Everything you put on the stack, while you are in your function, has to be freed in order to get to the correct jump-back-address and to avoid a potential segfault.

Fortunately C does this type of memory management automatically for us and frees all of our [automatic variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_variable) once they are considered to be 'out of scope'. To do that we need the exact size of what we have pushed onto the stack and that is why already the compiler needs to know that size.

To illustrate how the compiler translates your code and hard-codes these numbers, see here:

```
$ echo "int int_size = sizeof(int); int main(void) { int arr[] = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50}; }" |\ 
    gcc -c -xc -S -o- -masm=intel - 


    .file   ""
    .intel_syntax noprefix
    .text
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
# [...] removed int_size here to keep it shorter. its "4" ;)
main:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    push    rbp               # < backup rbp / stack base pointer
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    mov rbp, rsp              # < rsp / stack shift pointer = top of the stack
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    sub rsp, 32
    mov rax, QWORD PTR fs:40
    mov QWORD PTR -8[rbp], rax
    xor eax, eax
    mov DWORD PTR -32[rbp], 10  # < 10 is one element from the array
    mov DWORD PTR -28[rbp], 20  # < -28 means relative to the top of the stack
    mov DWORD PTR -24[rbp], 30 
    mov DWORD PTR -20[rbp], 40
    mov DWORD PTR -16[rbp], 50
    mov eax, 0
    mov rdx, QWORD PTR -8[rbp]
    xor rdx, QWORD PTR fs:40
    je  .L3
    call    __stack_chk_fail@PLT
.L3:
    leave
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 8.2.1 20181127"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Comment: Thanks alot! Very nice answer!

Comment: C allows runtime-variable array sizes for automatic storage.  (Of course not with initializers, but `int arr[n]` is allowed).  It's only at global scope (or for `static int arr[] = {1,2,3};` in a function) that it's necessary for the compiler to know the size, either from the length of the initializer list or from a constant size in the `[]`.  TL:DR: I think you're overcomplicating this by bringing up stack allocation.  That's good to understand, but not different from how it would work if you included the `[5]`.

Answer (score 16):

It's a convenience feature. The size of the array is deduced from the initializer so you don't have to spell it:

```
int arr[] = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50};
```

is equivalent with

```
int arr[5] = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50};
```

Another example of this (thanks to Eugene Sh.) is string initializers:

```
char str[] = "asd";
```

Is equivalent with

```
char str[4] = "asd";
```

---

One important thing to know is that when used as a type for a function parameter things are different. All of the next forms:

```
void foo(int v[])

void foo(int v[1])
void foo(int v[5])
void foo(int v[1000])
```

All are equivalent between themselves and they are *transformed* into this:

```
void foo(int* v)
```

Always use the latter (`void foo(int* v)`), never the other ones. Because the first forms make it look like you have an array type, but in reality what you have is a pointer. It's misleading.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, makes sense. However, why is the following correct ? char *ptr[3] = {"Hello", "test", "Hi"};  I mean, don't we have to use malloc() ?

Comment: @Meerkat Please ask another question. This one is quite different from the original one.

Comment: @Meerkat I also suggest you create a proper MCVE for your next question, and work on it a bit to understand what is going on... such as looking at variable contents in a debugger. These are so C language basics questions, that you should really try to explain what is the thing you have hard time understanding specifically, so answers don't need to be C language tutorials

Comment: What is a MCVE ? Never heard of that.

Comment: @Meerkat See [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That's also mentioned as part of the [How-to-Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guideline

Comment: Don't get me wrong, but the rules seem te be pretty srict. Second, I'm not interested in the "hows", which I can learn from books describing syntax, but I'm interested in the "whys". I would like to understand the inner workings of the language. I cannot find much information on the internet (books, pdfs), so I like asking questions on this forum as there seem to be alot of experts here.

Comment: @bolov  why shouldn't we use the array form as a function parameter ?

Comment: @Meerkat Q: why? A: because the C language has been designed like that. And it's also rather convenient.

Comment: @bolov  IMO `void (int f[])` is OK, but `void (int f[5])` can be misleading. But this is rather opiniated. But you've got my UV anyway

Comment: @bolov So they are all equivalent because the compiler throws away the numbers between brackets ?

Comment: @Meerkat (regarding learning about the "why"s from books) Well.. you actually can. Here is a prime example: [The Design and Evolution of C++ by Bjarne Stroustrup](https://www.google.com/search?ei=2n2GXMabGZGdkwWl35igCA&q=the+design+and+evolution+of+c%2B%2B+bjarne+stroustrup&oq=the+design+and+evolution+of+c%2B%2B+bjarne+stroustrup&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i22i30l2.1626.1792..1970...0.0..0.100.194.1j1......0....1..gws-wiz.Zk_qugqcU9Q)

Comment: @Bolov But that's c++ not c

Comment: @Meerkat it does more than that. Yes it completely throws away the numbers, but it converts what is looks like an array type to a pointer type.

Comment: @Bolov You seem to be from Romania (saw your account on this website). I like the Romanian language! Sounds alot like latin.

Comment: @Meerkat well, it'a latin language :p

Comment: @Bolov Yeah true off course :) But I mean from all romanic languages Romanian sounds the most like orignial latin.

Answer (score 7):

To complement the existing answer, quoting from the `C11`, chapter §6.7.9, P22

> If an array of unknown size is initialized, its size is determined by the largest indexed
>   element with an explicit initializer. The array type is completed at the end of its
>   initializer list.

So, the size of the array will be decide by the "largest indexed element", or, simply speaking, the count of elements present in the initializer list.

Comment: "largest indexed element" allows for designated-initializer syntax like `int arr[] = {[5] = 1};` to set the 5th element without spelling out the zeros for the earlier elements. 
 https://godbolt.org/z/f8jrTTsT5